# How to include sdl2

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use the `sdl2` package in Rust.

My project folder:

```
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
    ├── keyboard.rs
    └── main.rs
```

So far I did the following:
Added a `sdl2` line to my Cargo, where extern dependencies are handeled:
`Cargo.toml`:

```
// ...
[dependencies]
    sdl2 = "0.31"
```

To use `sdl2` in my `keyboard.rs`, I added the following lines:

```
extern crate sdl2;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
```

But when I try to compile (`cargo build`), I get the following error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Did you mean `keyboard::sdl2`?
 --> src/keyboard.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
  |     ^^^^ Did you mean `keyboard::sdl2`?

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Did you mean `keyboard::sdl2`?
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to load extern crates in other files than the `main.rs` file?

**edit 1:**

Adding the `extern crate sdl2;` to my `main.rs` did not solve the problem

Comment: You need to add an `extern crate sd12` in your main.rs. All external dependencies need to be linked at the top level.

Comment: the error still occurs

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem :/ You need to give us more information: how are you compiling? A simple `cargo build` or something else? Also: what Rust version (`rustc -V`) are you using? And please give us the full content of `main.rs` (at least all parts that are necessary to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, I need to declare extern dependencies at the root. When using a `lib.rs` file, it has to be written there:

`lib.rs`:

```
extern crate sdl2;
//...
```

in order to use it in the
`keyboard.rs` file:

```
use sdl2::keyboard::Scancode;
use sdl2;
// example code below
fn is_a_pressed(e: &sdl2::EventPump) -> bool {
    e.keyboard_state().is_scancode_pressed(Scancode::A)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need both a lib and main file. This may be your problem.

Comment: Could you explain your problem and your solution in more detail? In its current form, this Q&A is unlikely to help any future visitor. We don't like this here on SO (our mission is all about building a knowledge base for future visitors). By editing your question and answer, you could improve this situation and give knowledge back to the community.